# How to browse MDB file to DataGridView and TIF Images to ImageViewer

Tags: vb.net

Public Class CARD_DECK_ENTRY
    Public myConString As String
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing

```
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    End
    Operator_ID.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenFileToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True


    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & openFileDialog1.FileName
                Dim x As String = openFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(0, openFileDialog1.FileName.Length - 20) & "Images"
                con.ConnectionString = myConString
                con.Open()

                datagridshow()
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open. 

            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub CARD_DECK_ENTRY_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con.ConnectionString = myConString

    con.Open()

    datagridshow()

End Sub

Private Sub datagridshow()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Data001", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    con.Close()


End Sub
```

I get it now Tim, but now i'm about to load the images into a imageViewer with same time on browsing mdb. As you can see in the above codes, there was ("Select * from Data001", con) because it was a table i will be showing on the DataGridView. On the database there was a two table, those are "CardDeck" and "Data001." In CardDeck there was a "Image001" column. This column contains tif image names. On the folder where the database was found there was another folder on the same path(path of the database folder) named "Images". The column value of "Image001" will be found there. My point is how can I browse those "Image001" column value to a ImageViewer where those value are located in Folder "Images"?  Please help. :'(

Comment: You can use something like `Math.Round(dbCount,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. This will round 2.77... to 3.

Comment: change to `Double` to `Integer` i.e `Dim dbCount As Integer`

Comment: This worked for me, so there is another problem in your code. So, are you sure you are getting the right value in dbCount var?

Comment: im sure. im about to put 7 in variable batSz so that it will divide in the variable imgCount(20). the equivalent should be 3 instead of two. what am i going to do? any other answer?

Comment: Are you looking to round `imgCount / batSz` up to the next integer, or to the nearest integer?

Comment: to the nearest integer i guess? about 2.1 round as 3. even the decimal is only .1, what do you think the code im going to use?

Comment: i get it now. thanks to all of you guys.
it suppose to be, dbCount = CInt(Math.Ceiling(imgCount / batSz))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want get the round the output into the next Integer If yes then try this

```
Dim dbCount As Integer
```

---

```
Dim val, val1 As Integer
Dim intrslt As Integer
Dim dblrslt As Double

val = 20
val1 = 7
intrslt = (val / val1)' output : 3

dblrslt = (val / val1)' output : 2.85
```

or

use

```
Dim dbCount As Double = CInt(imgCount / batSz)
```

---

```
  Dim rslt As Double
  rslt = CInt((20 / 7)) ' output : 3
  rslt = Convert.ToInt32(Int(20 / 7)) ' output :2
```

[**`Demo`**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO)

Answer (score 1):

You want an integer division, VB.NET has it's own operator for this [`\`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx):

```
Dim result As Int32 = 25 \ 9 + 1
```

So the common [`/`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx)-operator returns a double with the result of the division. In C# one of both need to be floating point types to avoid integer division(dropping the remainder).

Another approach is to use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
result = CInt(Math.Ceiling(25 / 9))
```

There's a difference in both approaches. The first will always add +1 to the result whereas the `Math.Ceiling` will return only the next integer if there is a remainder.

Comment: result = CInt(Math.Ceiling(25 / 9))

Thanks to this.

Comment: ow, sorry. im beginner here in stackoverflow. when the first time I asked a question, i don't even know where are the real comments. i thought that your comments was just an advertise. lol, but thanks on your help.

Comment: hey team. do you know how to connect the database through using openfile dialog box?

Comment: Ow, it's Tim rather. sorry, my bad for mistaken ur name.

Comment: Hi Tim, can you help me browse an mdb file through using openfile dialog box? and update it through using datagrid?

Comment: @Jham: sorry, this is too broad. I can't write your code. You have to show own effort, then i(or others) can help to fix it.

Comment: I edited the question I've posted. Please take a look on the above, advance thanks Tim.